# Problem with itemisation

Tags: itemize

```
\subsection{IDENTITY :}
\begin{itemize}
\item Left Identity $:$ e_{l} $ \star $ a $=$ a
\item Right Identity $:$ a $\star $ e_{r} $=$ a 
\end{itemize}
```

i am not getting alphabet 'a' in the second item properly.what is the problem. please help.

Comment: Why are you switching in and out of math-mode? What is a “alphabet 'a'”? And have you seen the `Missing $` error? Just do `\item Left Identity: $e_{l} \star a = a$ \item Right Identity: $a \star e_{r} = a $` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your math is completely wrong, you sould be getting an error when you compile your example (BTW please include a full example, not a sniplet, makes it a lot easier to help).

This is the proper manner:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\subsection{IDENTITY :}
\begin{itemize}
\item Left Identity: $ e_{l}  \star  a = a$
\item Right Identity: $ a \star  e_{r} = a $ 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]